# find all possible combinations of two integers

Tags: javascript

Each time I can climb 1 or 2 steps to reach the top (3 steps for example)
1 + 1 + 1, 1 + 2, 2 + 1. There are three cases (scenarios). Here's my voodoo code (the thing is some numbers (missing) don't appear for n = 5 it's 1211. the solution would be to do the reverse string and store two versions of such strings in the hash, so duplicates will disappear and after the cycle sums them.

```js
function setCharAt(str, index, chr) {
  if (index > str.length - 1) return str;
  return str.substring(0, index) + chr + str.substring(index + 1);
}

let n = 9;
find(n);

function find(n) {
  let origin = n; //every loop n decreases by one when it 0 while returns false,
  let sum = 1;
  n -= 1; //because n once once of 1's (n = 5) 1+1+1+1+1 then 1111, 1112 etc. 
  if (n <= 1) return sum;

  while (origin <= n * 2) { //if n = 10; only"22222" can give 10, we don't go deeper
    let str = "1".repeat(n); //from "1" of n(4) to "1111"
    let copyStr = str;

    while (str.length === copyStr.length) { //at the end we get 2222 then 22221, 
      // therefore the length will change, we exit the loop
      let s = str.split('').reduce((a, b) => Number(a) + Number(b), 0); //countinng elems
      console.log(str, "=", s);
      if (s === origin) ++sum; //if elems equals the target we increase the amount by one
      let one = str.lastIndexOf("1");
      let two = str.lastIndexOf("2");

      if (str[one] === "1" && str[one + 1] === "2") {
        str = setCharAt(str, one, "2");
        str = setCharAt(str, one + 1, "1");
      } else {
        str = setCharAt(str, one, "2");
      }

    }
    --n;
  }
  console.log(sum)
}
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I can't understand the algorithm to combine all these cases. I wrote in a notebook, but I still did not understand how to iterate all values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood your question, you wanna for let say n = 5 get all combinations of 1 and 2 (when you sum it) that give a sum of 5 (11111, 1112, etc)?

It is most likely that you wanna use recursion in these kind of situations, because its much easier. If you have just two values (1 and 2) you can achieve this pretty easily:

```
getAllCombinations = (n = 1) => {

  const combinations = [];

  const recursion = (n, sum = 0, str = "") => {

    if (sum > n) return;

    if (sum === n) {
      combinations.push(str);
      return;
    }

    // Add 1 to sum
    recursion(n, sum + 1, str + "1");
    // Add 2 to sum
    recursion(n, sum + 2, str + "2");

  };

  recursion(n);

  return combinations;

};
```

Comment: great explanation.